# bios loading more sectors ... with virtual disk image as harddisk for qemu not working

Tags: bootloader, bios

I have been writing a 2 stage boot loader the first stage just loads the second stage and sets up the gdt and turns on protected mode and all . I went through several manuals and previous questions but still I am facing this issue . loading the sectors with BIOS int 0x13 call gives all zeros and I am not able to find out the reason. Here is my code for reading the sector. I tried to read even the first sector but that too gave all zeros in the memory.

```
    read:
    xorw    %ax,%ax
    movw    %ax,%es
    movw    $0x1000,%bx
    movb    $0x2, %ah   #command to read the sector
    movb    $0x80, %dl  #read from the hard disk
    movb    $0x1, %al  # read one sector
    movb    $0x1, %ch  #track no
    movb    $0x1, %cl  # read the first sector
    movb    $0x1 , %dh  # head number
    int     $0x13    
    jc      read
    movw    $0x11fe, %di
    movw    (%di),%ax
    cmpw     $0xaa55,%ax  # testing the signature
    jne     error
    ljmp    $0x0,$0x1000
```

So, as you can see I am trying to read the first sector again (just to test)but the memory contains all zeros
I am using the virtual disk image which I create using the following:

```
    dd if=/dev/zero of=obj/kern/kernel.img~ bs=512 count=20000 2>/dev/null
dd if=obj/boot/boot of=obj/kern/kernel.img~ conv=notrunc 2>/dev/null
dd if=obj/boot1/boot of=obj/kern/kernel.img~ seek=1 conv=notrunc 2>/dev/null
dd if=obj/kern/kernel of=obj/kern/kernel.img~ seek=3 conv=notrunc 2>/dev/null
mv obj/kern/kernel.img~ obj/kern/kernel.img
```

Please help me out with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the first sector is sector 1, track 0, head 0.

> 

The happy answer is that although writing a bootloader is the easy part, getting it to work is most satisfying.

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work. I am not sure if the virtual disk  I am creating can be access using the CHS standard. So I tried it with the LBA standard with the in and out instructions and it worked :) . Anyways thanks for the reply. Would really want to know the real reason behind this code failing.